# ASP.NET Session[] parameter doesn't work from page_load()

Tags: c#, asp.net

I`m making a nice ASP.NET site, where i save the user's details on the session upon login as follows:

```
 protected void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     //If details at the user/password textboxes are legit:
   Session["User"] = new User(LoginUserTB.Text, LoginPassTB.Text, null,  Class.UNDEF);
}
```

It works pretty fine, For example, I have a label named Welcome tag that's suppoused to change to a greeting including the username if a user is saved on the session. I programmed it like so, and it works.

**Page load:**

```
 if(Session["User"]!=null)
  WelcomeTag.Text = "Welcome, " + ((User)Session["User"]).Username + ".";
```

However, for some reason, it doesn't work properly on one of the labels. It's a master page label named StatusDesc, which is suppoused to include the date on the server and the username if there is one. On the page, i have the following code:

```
if (Session["User"] != null)
{
  ((Label)Master.FindControl("StatusDesc")).Text = "Currently logged to: " +  ((User)Session["User"]).Username + ".<br>" + ((Label)Master.FindControl("StatusDesc")).Text;
}
```

It worked before, and i`m certain about the master page component name - i didn't change it in the meantime; However, now, even if i am logged, it just won't show the Username line - only the date line, which it shows even if there is no user on the session.

Any idea why would such a thing happen? if you need me to provide other sections of the code, just ask.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: does it enter the `if (Session["User"] != null)` block?

Comment: Do you have an implementation for session refresh?

Comment: Notes: I do not have an implentation for session refresh. I also noticed on the first page you see after you log in you can actually see the "User" part in the status, but after that you cant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to understand the events those get fired in sequence inorder to set values to control

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dct97kc3%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

Image From MSDN (http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC386473.png)
[image: ASP.Net Page Life Cycle (Image From MSDN)]

(Image From CodeProject)
[image: ASP.Net Page Life Cycle With Master Page]

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. You just say: "You need to understand the events those get fired in sequence inorder to set values to control
." So... anything wrong with it?

Comment: Sangram, +1 for the diagram. Wonderful. But I doubt whether this answer the question

Comment: @PatrickHofman  I didn't had privilege to add comment till moment I posted answer, My point being was for one to understand why values of controls is getting lost, one needs to understand purpose & sequence of events that gets executed, for example e.g. Setting values of controls  Init event is every wrong idea

Comment: I know, but now OP doesn't know anything more to solve the issue.

Comment: @a-abramov if you can provide with sample example, I would be exactly able to pin point the problem.

Comment: nope it is from http://spazzarama.files.wordpress.com/2009/02/aspnet_page-control-life-cycle.jpg

Comment: Although I feel smarter now ( I was aware of the life cycle, but it's always nice to reread) i am not sure what is my mistake. Can you help me find it? It really is not about being lazy - I just really have no idea what have i done wrong. If you need me to post more parts of the code, let me know which and i will.

Comment: sample code re-generating scenario would be good, reason being there are lot of questions, like do you add control dynamically ?

Comment: where is this code,
if (Session["User"] != null)
{
  ((Label)Master.FindControl("StatusDesc")).Text = "Currently logged to: " +  ((User)Session["User"]).Username + ".<br>" + ((Label)Master.FindControl("StatusDesc")).Text;
}

Comment: It's on the pageLoad function. 

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["User"] != null)
            {
                ((Label)Master.FindControl("StatusDesc")).Text = "Currently logged to: " + ((User)Session["User"]).Username + ".<br>" + ((Label)Master.FindControl("StatusDesc")).Text;
            }
        }